# Is there a way to set a minimum number of characters that can be inserted in an edit in Delphi?

Tags: delphi-2010

The minimum number of characters that can be inserted in an edit is 10, I used this code but nevertheless the message keeps saying that there is not enough characters.

```
ilength := length(sDetails);
if (ilength IN [0..9] )
then showmessage('You have to insert more than 10 characters') else showmessage('Thank you') ;
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you describe. Consider this program:

`procedure Main;
const
  sDetails = '0123456789';
var
  ilength: Integer;
begin
  ilength := length(sDetails);
  Writeln(ilength);
  Writeln(ilength in [0..9]);
end;

begin
  Main;
  Readln;
end.`

The output is `10 FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show how you are assigning `sDetails` or what it actually contains when you get the wrong message displayed. However, you should not be using the `in` iterator to check the length, use arithmetic operators instead, eg:

```pascal
ilength := Length(sDetails);
if ilength < 10 then
  ShowMessage('You have to insert 10 or more characters')
else
  ShowMessage('Thank you');
```

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't explain anything.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan then feel free to post your own answer that explains what you think I'm missing.

Comment: I can't post an answer because I can't reproduce the behaviour described. The program in my comment demonstrates that. I don't think I need to post an answer in order to comment.